# Azure App Service Custom Domain limitation

Tags: azure-appservice, azure-custom-domain

We work with Azure App Service and custom domain feature to set the websites of our clients to our App service (with appropriate SSL for sure) The limitation of custom domain seems to be 250 or 500?  Someone has the truth? We products is a SAAS and the growth of our business depending to.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The number of custom domains per app is 500. See this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits) for all limits per App Service Plan tier.